# Remove WhiteSpaces from comma separated function parameters

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to get the Function Name and the parameters from an input with Regex. By now i'm able to get the function name but failing at the parameters because they are comma separated and ***sometimes*** have a leading whitespace.

Example of (messed up) input:

```
Function001(param1, param2,param3,param4, param5);
Function002(param1,param2, param3);
```

With the following regex i'm able to get the parameters but always with the leading whitespace...

```
((?<=\(|,).+?(?=,|\);))
```

i.e.

```
param1
_param2
param3
```

Is there a simple regex to get the parameters but without the whitespaces?
If possible I don't want to trim the input before going on and processing it.

**edit to cancel out any misleads**

Given are many strings like the on above:

```
Function001(param1, param2,param3,param4, param5);
Function002(param1,param2, param3);
```

Now I want one Regex for the FunctionName (That one works so no Codeexample for that) and one for the Parameters. Best would be the

```
Regex.Matches(inputString, pattern);
```

So I get any parameter and can process them. If possible I don't want to use Trim/Replace/etc. So my wished Output would be a Match for any parameter but without the spaces matched.

> Output:
>   param1
>   param2
>   param3
>   ...

A Parameter can be a simple string but also something like
`Function(param = value, param2,param3, param4 = value2);`

Comment: How are you defined whitespace? spaces, carrage returns, linefeeds, tabs, etc?

Comment: Just a space. Multiple spaces may be possible too

Comment: Did you read how trimming spaces from strings using regex instead of string handling methods brought down StackOverflow? clear code which runs faster is usually better unless you have a very good reason

Comment: you mean optional parameters.

Comment: @Rakitić: Yes in a way. But it's custom code/not C# that gets parsed and processed in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

´\s*´ stands for white space of any number. Put that to appropriate places outside the captured parts of your regex (which somehow looks strange - did some parts get lost when you posted it here?). 
Edit:
It may likely be `(?<=\(\s|,).+?(?=,|\s\);)`

Comment: The outer brackets are to much... `(?<=\(|,).+?(?=,|\);)` is what I use but it works to get the params with leading whitespace. I tried \s* but it just ignores it somehow... Could you post an examplecode?

Comment: The one you wrote didn't work but I modified it so I came to this regex: `(?<=\(|(,(?=[^, ])|,\s)).+?(?=,|\);)` This... somehow works finde :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use Regex?

I think this should work for you:

```
var input = "Function001(param1, param2,param3,param4, param5);";

var results = input.Split("( ,);".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

I get this out:

[image: result]

Comment: That looks nice for simple parameters. I forgot to mention that parameters can appear like this `param = value`. Anyways plus 1